# Do I need to declare instance variable in class?

Tags: javascript

I have declare a class like A, inside I would like to have some instance variables like a1, a2, do I need to declare before using them?

Comment: It would help people give you a better answer (and maybe not downvote) if you filled this question out with some example code.

Answer (score 0):

If by "instance variables" you mean properties, no, JavaScript doesn't currently have property *declarations*. You just assign to the property:

```
class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.someProperty = "some value";
    }
}
```

If the [class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) progresses (which it likely will, it's currently at Stage 3 of [the process](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/)), you could also write that like this:

```
class Example {
    someProperty = "some value";
}
```

And if you wanted the default initial value (`undefined`), you could just write:

```
class Example {
    someProperty;
}
```

...which looks a lot like a declaration and could be useful for IDE's doing code completion for you.

---

If you mean local variables within a constructor or function, not properties, then yes, you must declare them:

```
class Example {
    someMethod() {
        let someVariable = "some value"; // Local variable within `someMethod`
    }
}
```